# google maps no gestures working

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have created a Map Fragment that looks like the following :

```
  public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        final LatLng latlg = new LatLng(40.730610,  -73.935242);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlg));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlg));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));


    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml :

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="tagonsoft.com.kidgonet.gui.fragments.MapsFragment" />
```

And I call the following fragment from an activity :

```
 public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           Fragment mFragment = null;
            mFragment = new MapsFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_overview, mFragment).commit();
           }          
    }
```

And the following xml is the content of MyActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_overview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I do see the Map View, It works fine. The only problem is that I cannot drag the map to see other places or zoom the map.

I have followed the google's map activity model. When I started the MapsActivity(offered by google) it was everything fine. The only thing that I have changed was to make MapsActivity a fragment. I tried with `googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the problem. The code from above works correctly . It was my mistake, I have implemented a navigation drawer too ,and that navigation drawer was above map view  and that was why I didn't have access to map dragging or any gesture.